# using performSegueWithIdentifier with selector method

Tags: objective-c, ios7, xcode5

What I am trying to accomplish is extremely simple.  I have three UIBarButtonItems added to my navigation bar programmatically. I then want the UIBarButtonItems to trigger segues programmatically, and I just want the segue to execute. So far my code is failing and I've been on this for 6 and a half hours, and I'm still unsure as to what I'm missing in code.

here's my VC .h

```
@interface RGStemsViewController : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic, readonly) UIStoryboardSegue *stemsToAddGroup;

- (void)addGroupItemInvoked:(id)sender;


@end
```

and my VC .m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

    self.navigationController.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[UIColor whiteColor] forKey:NSForegroundColorAttributeName];


    UIBarButtonItem *addGroupItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:self action:@selector(addGroupItemInvoked:)];

    UIBarButtonItem *searchItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemSearch target:self action:nil];
    UIBarButtonItem *optionsItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"optionsIconAlternative.png"] style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:nil];

    NSArray *actionButtonItems = @[optionsItem, searchItem];
    NSArray *groupButtonItem = @[addGroupItem];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = actionButtonItems;
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItems = groupButtonItem;

    self.navigationController.navigationBar.barTintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:153/256.0 green:204/256.0 blue:51/256.0 alpha:1.0];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{

}

- (void)addGroupItemInvoked:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender
{
    [self performSeguewithIdentifier:@"stemsToAddGroup" sender:sender];
}
```

I connected the segue by right clicking the view controller on the bottom bar of the view controller and rightclickdragging to the destination view, I think I need to use the prepareSegueWithIdentifier method

Apparently I have not declared the selector in my @interface, or at least that's what the my errors keep saying, what seems to be the problem here?

The full .m

```
@implementation RGStemsViewController

@synthesize stemsToAddGroup;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

    self.navigationController.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[UIColor whiteColor] forKey:NSForegroundColorAttributeName];


    UIBarButtonItem *addGroupItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:self action:@selector(addGroupItemInvoked:)];

    UIBarButtonItem *searchItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemSearch target:self action:nil];
    UIBarButtonItem *optionsItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"optionsIconAlternative.png"] style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:nil];

    NSArray *actionButtonItems = @[optionsItem, searchItem];
    NSArray *groupButtonItem = @[addGroupItem];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = actionButtonItems;
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItems = groupButtonItem;

    self.navigationController.navigationBar.barTintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:153/256.0 green:204/256.0 blue:51/256.0 alpha:1.0];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{

}

- (void)addGroupItemInvoked:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender
{
    [self performSeguewithIdentifier:@"stemsToAddGroup" sender:self];
}


@end
```

Comment: Can we see the full .m? Including the @implementation line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you need to set the action for `searchItem` and `optionsItem`?

Comment: I think you're right actually, I'm missing something in the declaration of my UIBarButtonItems..

Comment: no, sorry, I found the error, I had the method loose-ended in a method where it was not needed.